# How to draw a dataframe column of dtype = datetime64[ns] on x- axis of a matplot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, timeserieschart

I wanted to draw two time series on the same plot of matplotlib. 
I have a pandas dataframe [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyiIH.png)
Where the Date column is of dtype= datetime64[ns] as x-axis and Close, Open column are type=np.float64 as y-axis

Im trying the code

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.xticks( df['Index'].values)
plt.plot(df['Close'])
plt.plot(df['Open'])
plt.show()
```

But it is showing errors. Where should I improve ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot only some columns of your df(in this example 'col1' and 'col2'), you can do so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,11, 3,'2018-04-02 20:30'], [15, 20, 5, '2018-04-02 20:31'], [20, 25, 6, '2018-04-02 20:40'], [10, 12, 8, '2018-04-02 20:45']], columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3' ,'Dates'])
print (df)

   col1  col2  col3             Dates
0    10    11     3  2018-04-02 20:30
1    15    20     5  2018-04-02 20:31
2    20    25     6  2018-04-02 20:40
3    10    12     8  2018-04-02 20:45

df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.set_index(['Dates'],inplace=True)
df.loc[:,['col1','col2']].plot()
plt.show()
```

In your case this should work:

```
df.loc[:,['Open','Close']].plot()
```